# For the probability function p(n) which is recursive, how to obtain the maximum n under the condition p(n)≤0.1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, recursion, probability-limit-theorems

here is the recursive function
$p(1) = 0$
$p(n+1) = (1-10^{-8}n)p(n)+10^{-8}n$
I want to get the maximum n that makes $p(n)≤0.1$　
I tried to get the solution of the function but it failed. It seems possible to use something like Chernoff Bounds,Chevyshev’s Inequality,Markov’s Inequality to calculate the bound of n, but I don't know how to start.
The original question is to choose 8 numbers from $0-9$ arbitrarily, arrange and combine them in order. Find the largest n that after repeating n times, probability of duplicates in n numbers$≤0.1$
(I want to find largest n as possible,under the premise of computability, without computer calculation. The answer may not be the number exactly at the critical point, but the number close to the critical point in the calculable range)
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a computer, the maximum value of $n$ for which $p(n) \le 0.1$ is $$p(4590) \approx 0.0999628 \\
p(4591) \approx 0.100004.$$

Let $c = 10^{-8}$.  Note that the given recursion may be written as $$1 - p(n+1) = (1 - cn)(1 - p(n)).$$

This suggests defining an auxiliary sequence $b(n) = \log (1 - p(n))$, hence
$$\log(1 - p(n+1)) = \log (1 - cn) + \log(1 - p(n))$$ or $$b(n+1) = \log(1 - cn) + b(n)$$ and we get the telescoping sum $$b(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \log(1 - cn) = \log \prod_{k=0}^n (1 - ck),$$ consequently $$p(n) = 1 - \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1 - ck).$$

Comment: It's elegant, but I'm finding an answer within the range that can be shown by hand calculation. is there a better way to find the biggest $n$ that meets the condition $0.9≤\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1 - ck)$?

Comment: @musk I imagine there may be a way to approximate the finite product as a continuous function of $n$, but even if such an approximation could be inverted to solve for $n$, it would not give an exact solution.  Therefore, you are not likely to find something that can be easily computed.  If the approximation is "good," then it could get you in the neighborhood of the exact value, which could then be found by computer evaluation.

Comment: The answer I am looking for may not be the number exactly at the critical point, but the number close to the critical point in the calculable range. Is there a way to approximate the finite product?